# There is no DoubleClick event for ListView control in .NET CF 3.5

Tags: .net, compact-framework

In my project, tree is a list of customers displayed in an ListView control, When user double clicks (or taps) on an item I should show the details of that customer,

But there is no double click (or click event, mouse up and down events etc.) event in .NET CF 3.5 ListView control (we only have ItemActive and SelectedIndexChanged events)

Is there anyone has figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using popup menu with functions that I need (like edit/delete/create new).

Comment: I did the same thing, once I thought to dig into win32 but I let it go :)

Answer (score 2):

ItemActivate event is exactly what you need to replace the double click

Comment: I believe you meant the ItemActivate event.  That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly WM doesn't support double tap out of the box, because it's too tricky to have users do reliably, so thats why there is [tap-and-hold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839437.aspx) which can be used to show a context menu after you have held the tap for a certain short period of time.