# How to implement tap-and-hold feature for Button/Button2 in .NET CF

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, opennetcf, tapandhold

I need to catch both events for Button: OnClicked and tapped/holed/released.

Unfortunately it is not possible correctly handle both OnClick and OnDoubleClick events - both OnClick  and OnDoubleClick are raised.

Comment: What control are you trying to raise a double click from? I'm not sure I have come across any CF apps that use a double click so it may not be the most intuitive interface if you do get it working.

Comment: Tap and hold seems to be the way people are going : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952244/there-is-no-doubleclick-event-for-listview-control-in-net-cf-3-5

Comment: OpenNetCF Button or LinkLabeL (standard or from OpenNetCF)